# Using images and CSS to offline fallback page

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am trying to set up my website to have a fallback page when it is loaded without an internet connection. To do that, I am following [this guide on web.dev: "Create an offline fallback page"](https://web.dev/offline-fallback-page/)

I modified the example ServiceWorker in the article to fit my purposes, including being able to serve external CSS and images in the fallback offline page:

```
// Incrementing OFFLINE_VERSION will kick off the install event and force
// previously cached resources to be updated from the network.
const OFFLINE_VERSION = 1;
const CACHE_NAME = "offline";
// Customize this with a different URL if needed.
const OFFLINE_URL = "offline.html";

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
        (async () => {
            const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
            // Setting {cache: 'reload'} in the new request will ensure that the response
            // isn't fulfilled from the HTTP cache; i.e., it will be from the network.
            await cache.add(new Request(OFFLINE_URL, { cache: "reload" }));
            await cache.add(new Request("offline.css", { cache: "reload" }));
            await cache.add(new Request("logo.png", { cache: "reload" }));
            await cache.add(new Request("unsupportedCloud.svg", { cache: "reload" }));
        })()
    );
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
    // Tell the active service worker to take control of the page immediately.
    self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
    // We only want to call event.respondWith() if this is a navigation request
    // for an HTML page.
    if (event.request.mode === "navigate") {
        if (event.request.url.match(/SignOut/)) {
            return false;
        }
        event.respondWith(
            (async () => {
                try {
                    const networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
                    return networkResponse;
                } catch (error) {
                    // catch is only triggered if an exception is thrown, which is likely
                    // due to a network error.
                    // If fetch() returns a valid HTTP response with a response code in
                    // the 4xx or 5xx range, the catch() will NOT be called.
                    console.log("Fetch failed; returning offline page instead.", error);

                    const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
                    const cachedResponse = await cache.match(OFFLINE_URL);
                    return cachedResponse;
                }
            })()
        );
    }
});
```

However, when the `offline.html` page loads it does is unable to load the images and the CSS; the images fail to load with a 404 error and the request for the CSS doesn't even show in the Network tab of the browser dev console.

I would expect the images and CSS to be fetched from the ServiceWorker cache, but it seems that neither is.

Am I missing something on how ServiceWorkers cache requests or how they fetch them? Or on how to design the offline fallback page to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were a few reasons why the assets were not being found.

**The first reason** is because when they were saved to cache, they were saved with the entire path where they are stored alongside the Service Worker file.

So the path that was saved was something along the lines of `static/PWA/[offline.css, logo.png, unsupportedCloud.svg]` but the path of the page that requested them was in the root. In `offline.html` I had to reference them as such: `<img src="static/PWA/unsupportedCloud.svg" class="unsupported-cloud" />`.

**The second reason** is that the Service Worker only checks for `fetch` events were of type navigation. In my example you can see I had written `if (event.request.mode === "navigate") {...}` so we only attempted to use the cache that we set up in navigation events, which would not catch `fetch` events to get assets. To fix that, I set up a new check for `no-cors` event modes: `else if (event.request.mode === "no-cors") {...}`.

These two fixes let me get assets from the offline cache that I set up on Service Worker installation. With some other minor fixes, this addresses my question!